# Запуск проекта на nodejs с помощью pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

Хочу настроить на сервере автозапуск файла index.js. Однако при запуске с помощью pm2 - start /var/www/Название_проекта/index.js выводит ошибку

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"
    at Function.render (/var/www/Kopeyka/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/Kopeyka/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
    at /var/www/Kopeyka/index.js:50:7
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

т.к необходимо запускать файл из директории его расположения. Я все перерыл и не пойму как его правильно запускать с помощью pm2.

Comment: Попробовал так же запустить с помощью systemd Однако проблема осталась все та же

Comment: `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"`, что импортируете из директории views в проекте? пакеты установили?